# NGINX - FILE NOT FOUND

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

i need help with my nginx config. At the moment I have a fully functioning Nextcloud instance, accessible from a subdomain. I tested my setup with a wordpress docker and a manuell install, with the same outcome.

The problem is with my wordpress installation, Nginx will not access the files and i am not able to access the wordpress UI. Could this habe something todo with file privileges? Because the error logs don´t show any file path, but Nginx runs and does not show config errors.

**`/swag/nginx/error.log` entry**

> 2021/09/20 15:33:22 [error] 473#473: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: ""

If i need to supply further information/files, let me know!

```
# REDIRECT WWW TO https://[domain.com]
server {
 listen 80;
 listen 443 ssl http2;
 server_name www.<DOMAIN>; 
 return 301 https://<DOMAIN>$request_uri;
}

# REDIRECT HTTP TRAFFIC TO https://[domain.com]
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <DOMAIN>; 
    return 301 https://<DOMAIN>$request_uri;
}

# BLOG SITE
server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;
 server_name <DOMAIN>;

## Source: https://github.com/1activegeek/nginx-config-collection
## READ THE COMMENT ON add_header X-Frame-Options AND add_header Content-Security-Policy IF YOU USE THIS ON A SUBDOMAIN YOU WANT TO IFRAME!

##NOTE: The add_header Content-Security-Policy won't work with duckdns since you don't own the root domain. Just buy a domain. It's cheap
## Settings to add strong security profile (A+ on securityheaders.io/ssllabs.com)

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Robots-Tag none; #SET THIS TO index IF YOU WANT GOOGLE TO INDEX YOU SITE!
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://*.$server_name https://$server_name"; ## Use *.domain.com, not *.sub.domain.com (*.$server_name) when using this on a sub-domain that you want to iframe!
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://*.$server_name" always; ## Use *.domain.com, not *.sub.domain.com (*.$server_name) when using this on a sub-domain that you want to iframe!
add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin";

 
 client_max_body_size 0; 
#Manuell install 
 root /mnt/user/appdata/swag/www/wordpress/;
#Docker
#   root /mnt/user/appdata/www/wordpress; 
index index.html index.php;
  
location ~ /\. {
deny all;
} 
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$query_string; 
}

 
# PHP
 location ~ \.php$ {
 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
 # With php7-cgi alone:
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 # With php7-fpm:
 #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


 }
 
 fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
 fastcgi_buffers 64 4k; 
}
```

Comment: First of all the NGINX configuration is always very helpfull. Please share your current configuration.

Comment: Most likely you set `SCRIPT_FILENAME` FastCGI variable to some wrong value. Please add nginx configuration to your question (you can omit private info like domain name, certificate filenames/paths etc.)

Comment: Could you explain which file the fastcgi variable needs to point to? I already tried changing it, but nothing helped. Thanks for the replies so far

Comment: @Béla As for me, everything looks ok with your config. To debug further, you can temporary describe some debug format using `log_format` directive and add something like `script filename: $document_root$fastcgi_script_name` to the log format. Restart nginx and check a log entries - what file it is trying to access during root trquest? It should be `/mnt/user/appdata/www/wordpress/index.php`.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I tried what you suggested and as you suspected it wrote this in the access.log: 
26/Sep/2021:16:45:13 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.10>
/mnt/user/appdata/swag/www/wordpress/index.php

Comment: @Béla Again, everything looks ok. But for some reason PHP-FPM can't open a PHP file. Sorry, I don't know how to help further.

Comment: @IvanShatsky That’s unfortunate, but thanks for your effort

Comment: Not sure if you need slash after root path. I saw other example without slash. How about removing it?

Comment: @Darius.V I already tested that, it doesn't change the path.

Comment: @Béla - show us docker-compose.yml . fastcgi_pass might be wrong.

Comment: @Darius.V The server runs unraid os and as far as I know, the file is not available on Unraid

Comment: which file is not available on Unraid?

Comment: I cant access the compose file. I´m not an expert on docker, but i have not been able to find the compose file